# Cancel a dynamic import in React useEffect hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I'm trying to build a component that takes a component as a prop, checks a folder for a dynamic import and returns either that component or the prop component.

```
const DynamicComponent = ({ element }) => {
  
  const [component, setComponent] = useState(element)
  
  useEffect(() => {
    import(`/components/${element.type.name}`)
      .then(module => {
        setComponent(module.default)
      })
  }, [element])

  return component
}
```

This does work, with the minor caveat that in production the component names are minified so I have to pass an additional prop like `elementName` to make the folder path correct.

However, I'm not sure how to properly clean up or cancel this import in `useEffect`. What would be the correct method for this in React?

Comment: checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72096891/useeffect-cleanup-in-react-18) question, it's kinda similar

Comment: [That](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72096891/useeffect-cleanup-in-react-18) question doesn't ask the proper cleanup, just why is the tried wrong.