# useEffect cleanup in React 18

Tags: reactjs, next.js, use-effect, locomotive-scroll

i'm using locomotive scroll with next.js, after react v18 my clean up stage is stopped working... Can someone explain why?

```
useEffect(() => {
let scroll;
import("locomotive-scroll").then((locomotiveModule) => {
  scroll = new locomotiveModule.default({
    el: document.querySelector("[data-scroll-container]"),
    smooth: true,
  });
});

return () => {
  scroll.destroy();
}});
```

I have error "Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'destroy')"

*If I down install react to 17 version all working fine

Comment: Have you tried adding a check to make sure `scroll` is defined before calling `scroll.destroy()`? E.g. `if (scroll) scroll.destroy();`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React v18 has introduced new dev-mode check regarding `useEffect` idempotency.  Your effects will be called once, then immediately destroyed and recreated again.

In your case problem is `import` takes some time (network request must be made), so value is assigned to `scroll` variable with some delay. Unfortunately, your cleanup is called before that, so `scroll` is `undefined`. It's kind of race condition and it would also occur in React v17, but less frequently as it depends on several characteristics (CPU power, network speed).

For details see this document: https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/08/react-18-upgrade-guide.html#updates-to-strict-mode

Answer (score 0):

As far as I find out then React vs18 useEffect auto run cleanup.
You can find it at [React18](https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/29/react-v18.html)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).